# com.w3c.dom.Document without <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

Tags: java, xml

I am creating a `com.w3c.dom.Document` from a `String` using this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<a><b id="5"/></a>")));
```

When I `System.out.println(xmlToString(document))`, I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><a><b id="5"/></a>
```

Everything is ok, but I don't want the XML to have the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` declaration, because I have to sign the  with private key and embed to soap envelope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a [`Transformer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) and set the [`OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#OMIT_XML_DECLARATION) property to `"yes"`:

```
Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
```

Please note you could also:

- Use a [`StreamSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html) instead of a `DOMSource` to feed the `String` directly to the transformer, if you don't really need the `Document`.
- Use a [`DOMResult`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMResult.html) instead of a `StreamResult` if you wanted to output a `Document`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have another problems, trying to solve them myself! :)